# TaskDialog as modal Dialog

Tags: vb.net, windows-api-code-pack, taskdialog

I am using TaskDialog and its really nice and i like it instead of normal messagebox. However i noticed that Show() of the TaskDialog allow user to go back to form and do something... I mean its not blocking Form till user close TaskDialog clicking on OK or whatever. I checked and can't find instead of Show - ShowDialog that would block untill TaskDialog will be close. Is there a way to achieve that?

e.g code:

```
 Dim dialog As New TaskDialog()
        AddHandler dialog.Opened, AddressOf taskDialog_Opened
        With dialog
            dialog.Text = "Hello Task Dialog"
            dialog.Caption = "Hello Task Dialog"
            dialog.Show()       
        End With
```

Comment: I get "TaskDialog is not defined" using Visual Studio 2017 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for regarding blocking is `modal`.  If you use the `OwnerWindowHandle` property you can make it modal to a form:

```
Using td As New TaskDialog
    td.Caption = "Some Error "
    td.StandardButtons = TaskDialogStandardButtons.Ok
    td.Text = "Something truly horrible has happened!"
    td.OwnerWindowHandle = Me.Handle    ' current form handle
    td.Show()
End Using
```

If your app has more than one form showing, access will only be blocked to that owner.  Also note the use of a `Using` block to dispose of it and free resources when done.